# Intellisense not showing syntax errors for cmake project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, cmake, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I am using a newly installed Visual Studio 2019 for a cmake project. The Intellisense for code completion (i.e. function and constant names) works fine. However, the red underlining syntax errors (i.e. missing semicolon, wrong param type, undefined variable) are missing from the text editor.

I set IntelliSense mode to `windows-msvc-x64` in `CMakeSettings.json` and used Ninja as default cmake generator.

How do I enable real-time syntax error detection in a cmake project? Is this possible at all?

Comment: Hi pbeta, does the issue still block you? You can check if it helps after you define the xx.cpp in CMakeLists.txt file, and regenerate the cmake cache :) And feel free to let me know if there's any update!

Answer (score 1):

> How do I enable real-time syntax error detection in a cmake project?
>   Is this possible at all?

Please check if you get the `No Configurations` tip for the `xx.cpp` where the Intellisense is not supported.

[image]

For Cmake projects in VS, when you create or add a new `xx.cpp` file to current project, you need to define the source file in `CMakeLists.txt` and then regenerate the `Cmake cache`, After that the Intellisense can support all functions for the `xx.cpp` file.

[image]

**Workaround:**

So for your issue, assuming you have created a new `Test.cpp` file in the project, **first** you should make sure the `Test.cpp` file is defined in the first `CMakeLists.txt` file, then [switch to the target view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/get-started-linux-cmake?view=vs-2019#switch-to-targets-view) to check if the `Test.cpp` file is under the `ProjectName(executable)` level. If you can't find `Test.cpp` in `ProjectName(executable)` level like this:

[image]

Right-click the project=>generate cache and if it succeeds, you'll find the Test.cpp under `ProjectName(executable)`. And only when you can find the `xx.cpp` under the ProjectName(executable), all code in the `xx.cpp` can get full support of Intellisense(i.e. missing semicolon).

[image]